# postgres 9.6 - recursive query CTE for hierachical data - distinct - duplicated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, distinct, recursive-query

I'm using Postgres 9.6 and I'm trying to recreate the level structure from a table with parents relationships.

I used a WITH RECURSIVE query; what I'm trying to do is to fetch for each `employee_id` the one with max level, but I'm messing up something, since despite using `DISTINCT`, there are still duplicated rows.

code:

```
-- source table 1
nov=# select comp_user_id, id from corp_companyuserprofile limit 10;
   comp_user_id   | id
------------------+----
 ffadmin          |  1
 clientadmin      |  4
 ca               |  5
 GGAdmin bb .     |  9
 comp_pa          | 10
 DEONI2           | 11
 RNoeleded        | 12
 asuhguhbnd       | 13
 KxxxxChan        | 14
 nmwaffmin        | 15

-- source table 2
nov=# select * from company_managerrelation limit 10;
  id  | mgr_type | employee_id | manager_id
------+----------+-------------+------------
 3932 | mgr      |         485 |         15
 3933 | mgr      |         526 |        527
 3934 | ind_mgr  |         351 |        304
 3935 | mgr      |         617 |        619
 3936 | ind_mgr  |         184 |         43
 3937 | mgr      |        1033 |       1023
 3938 | ind_mgr  |         312 |         25
 3939 | mgr      |         566 |        541
 3940 | mgr      |         394 |        390
 3941 | mgr      |         438 |        462
```

---

```
-- getting hierarchical structure with levels
with recursive cup_from_parents as
(
  select c.id, c.comp_user_id, '{}' :: int [] as parents, 0 as level,
   m.employee_id, m.manager_id
 from corp_companyuserprofile c LEFT JOIN corp_managerrelation m
     on c.id = m.employee_id
 where m.manager_id is NULL
 union all
  select c.id, c.comp_user_id, parents || m.manager_id, level+1,
       m.employee_id, m.manager_id
  from cup_from_parents p
  join corp_managerrelation m
  on m.manager_id = p.id
  join corp_companyuserprofile c
  on c.id = m.employee_id
  where not c.id = any(parents)
)
select gg.id, gg.comp_user_id, gg.parents, max(gg.level) as max_level from (
  select distinct on (cfp.id, cfp.parents, cfp.comp_user_id, cfp.level) cfp.id, cfp.comp_user_id, cfp.parents, cfp.level
  from cup_from_parents cfp
  join corp_managerrelation cmr
  on cfp.id = cmr.employee_id
) as gg
  group by (gg.id, gg.comp_user_id, gg.parents, gg.level)
order by gg.level DESC;
```

---

```
 id  | comp_user_id |                       parents                       | max_level
-----+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523} |        13
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523} |        13
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,24,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 521 | FAUCHMY1     | {13,283,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}    |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,531,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,530,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,529,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,528,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,527,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,526,525,523}     |        12
 522 | LARAMMA1     | {13,283,24,296,532,531,530,529,528,527,525,523}     |        12
...
```

Any help about this?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of data in your question. It is difficult to figure out how in the given example the data from the cornerstone_cornerstoneuserprofile table is linked to the data from company_managerrelation limit, these `id` are completely unrelated.

Comment: @krokodilko apologies for the mistake, the correct name for the `cornerstone_cornerstoneuserprofile` table is `corp_companyuserprofile `, i corrected that in the code sample.


`corp_companyuserprofile` and `company_managerrelation` are related through the `corp_companyuserprofile.id` and `company_managerrelation.employee_id` and `company_managerrelation.manager_id`.